# I popped one | I'm on one. What it mean?

Tags: meaning, lyrics

On "Trust Issues" song, The Weeknd say it.
When he says "I popped one" it mean **he ingested a drug** or it mean **he have no money**?

When he says "I'm on one", it mean **he have only one more drug** or it mean **he is high**?

And "I'm on a few" what it mean?

> [Hook]
>   I popped one
>   Fuck it, I popped one
>   Oh girl, I'm on one
>   Fuck it, I popped one
>   I popped one
>
> [Verse 2]
>   Girl, I'm lying, I'm on a few
>   Don't you worry, this ain't new
>   Can we take this to your spot?
>   I'm on eviction number 2
>   'Cause I popped one, oh
>   Fuck it, I popped one
>   Oh yeah

Comment: Song lyrics are so totally off-topic. But in this case..it sounds like "pop a **pill**".

Comment: I don't understand how *popping one* could be associated with money. And while it could easily refer to pills, it could also be referring to bubble wrap used in packaging …

Comment: Thanks for comment, the way of thinking will help me in the future. I got the meaning by here [link](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=popped)

Comment: @YannLopes If song lyrics are off-topic here as Rattler says (your question currently has 3 votes to close), you'd be welcome to ask this question at [literature.se] instead, where we accept questions about the meaning and interpretation of song lyrics.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because song lyric interpretation is off-topic on this site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think Drake or any performers in his genre have lyrics discussing that they're in financial peril. He's definitely talking about a drug/narcotic in some kind of pill form. "On" something is a term used to describe being high or influenced by something. Similar usage outside substances could be "[I'm on a cloud 9](https://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/on-cloud-nine.html)" to describe being happy.

The most telling [lyrics in the song](https://www.google.com/search?kgmid=/g/1q5jx64t1&hl=en-US&q=drake%20trust%20issues&kgs=0a1b3ced09a074f3&shndl=0&source=sh/x/kp/osrp&entrypoint=sh/x/kp/osrp#wptab=s:H4sIAAAAAAAAAONgVuLRT9c3LDTNqjAzKTF8xOjJLfDyxz1hKYdJa05eY7Ti4grOyC93zSvJLKkU0uFig7KUuASkUDRqMEjxcaGI8Oxi0ktJTUsszSmJL0lMsspOttLPLS3OTNYvSk3OL0rJzEuPT84pLS5JLbLKqSzKTC5exCpZUgQUUMgsLi5NLVZIKUrMTlWAyAEAkIZXOakAAAA) are that it's a **strong one**. Also this makes references to partying/mixing.

```
Two white cups and I got that drink
It could be purple, it could be pink
Depending on how you mix that sh*t
Money to be got, and I'mma get that sh*t
'Cause I'm on one, f*** it I'm on one
```

Not clear what exactly it is. The fact that he uses specific integer numbers (one or maybe two) essentially eliminates anything that he'd snort, smoke, inhale. To me, this infers it's a pill of some kind. I'm sure he'd be happy to tell you if you can get his attention on [twitter](https://twitter.com/Drake) (if you tell him the folks at english.stackexchange.com are curious, he'll probably drop everything and reply right away).

Comment: The song is a remix with The Weeknd. [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YVCV6hyv7ac)

Comment: @YannLopes Thanks. I am not too familiar not a musical expert. I appreciate you accepting the answer.